# How to get source/line number for IL instruction using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, symbols, pdb-files, mono.cecil

I'm using Mono.Cecil to write a simple utility that looks for type/method usage within .NET assemblies (ex. calling ToString on enums).

I am able to get find the method, but it would be cool to display the source/line information to the user. Is this possible with Mono.Cecil?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible. First you should read the guide from the Mono.Cecil wiki about [debugging symbols](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Debug-symbols).

Make sure you have Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll near Mono.Cecil.dll, set the ReaderParameters to read the symbols as indicated in the guide, and then, instructions who have a sequence point in the pdb file will have their `SequencePoint` property non null, with line information available. The `Document` property of the `SequencePoint` holds the name of the source file.

Comment: Thanks - that did it! I got confused that not all instructions have SequencePoint but when you think about it, it makes sense. Thank you again :)