# How to get line number of Instruction using Mono.Cecil 0.10.2?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I have a Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction object representing a method call in code.  I want to get the line number of the method call in the source file.

This old posting mentions using the SequencePoint property of the Instruction object: [How to get source/line number for IL instruction using Mono.Cecil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502775/how-to-get-source-line-number-for-il-instruction-using-mono-cecil).  However, I do not see this property in version 0.10.2 of Mono.Cecil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here: http://cecil.pe/post/149243207656/mono-cecil-010-beta-1

Instruction.SequencePoint was removed.  You must now use:

```
MethodDefinition method = ...;
Instruction instr = ...;
SequencePoint seqPoint = method.DebugInformation.GetSequencePoint(instr);
```